# read_tsv stalls: is this an encoding issue?

Tags: r, encoding, readr

I apologize in advance for the lack of specificity of this post but I can't provide a reproducible example in this case. I'm trying to read a tab-separated data file with R readr's `read_tsv`. The data is from a confidential source so I can't share it, even just the problematic part. `read_tsv` stalls around 20% of reading progress and unless I kill R quickly, my RAM usage starts blowing up to the point that my computer freezes (I'm on Ubuntu 18.04). Specifically, I'm running:

```
read_tsv(file = path_to_file, 
         skip = 10e6, 
         n_max = 1e5)
```

I'm skipping lines and setting n_max to vaguely isolate where the problem is and run faster tests. I also tried setting `read_tsv`'s locale to `locale(encoding = 'latin1')` without success. I tried inspecting this problematic part by reading it with readr's `read_lines`:

```
read_lines(file = path_to_file, 
           skip = 10e6, 
           n_max = 1e5)
```

There's no reading problem there: I'm getting a list of character strings. I ran `validUTF8` on all of them and they all seem valid. I just have no idea what type of problem could cause `read_tsv` to stall. Any ideas?

Comment: Please try with `data.table::fread` (would be faster) on a fresh R session

Comment: How large is the file? May just be that it's too large to fit in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It seems like it came from inappropriate handling of quoting characters with the default `read_tsv` `quote` option. Using `quotes = ""` instead made it work smoothly.